# Ranking Averages by Criteria

Tags: powerbi, dax, ranking

here is the deal... (actually I've solved it but I am sure there is an easier way)

my table is :

| Department ID | Criteria 1 | Criteria 2 | Criteria 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DEP 001 | 4 | 5 | 3 |
| DEP 002 | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| DEP 003 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
| DEP 004 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| DEP 001 | 4 | 4 | 5 |
| DEP 003 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| DEP 002 | 2 | 2 | 4 |
| DEP 003 | 3 | 5 | 2 |
| DEP 002 | 5 | 2 | 5 |
| DEP 005 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| DEP 001 | 1 | 5 | 3 |
| DEP 002 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| DEP 003 | 4 | 2 | 5 |
| DEP 005 | 3 | 4 | 1 |
| DEP 002 | 5 | 5 | 4 |
| DEP 005 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| DEP 001 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| DEP 002 | 3 | 1 | 5 |

I am trying to find the top 1 average in each criteria.
I've used unpivot, creating new table and then calculated column to find the result.

First Unpivoting

```
let
    Source = YourTableName,
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Department ID", type text}, {"Criteria 1", Int64.Type}, {"Criteria 2", Int64.Type}, {"Criteria 3", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Department ID"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns"
```

Second calculated Table :

```
Max Avg = 
VAR _cr1 =
    SUMMARIZE (
        'YourTableName (unpivoted)',
        'YourTableName (unpivoted)'[Department ID],
        'YourTableName (unpivoted)'[Attribute],
        "Criteria Avg",
            CALCULATE (
                AVERAGE ( 'YourTableName (unpivoted)'[Value] ),
                ALLEXCEPT (
                    'YourTableName (unpivoted)',
                    'YourTableName (unpivoted)'[Department ID],
                    'YourTableName (unpivoted)'[Attribute]
                )
            )
    )
RETURN
    _cr1
```

and finally the calculated rank column and filter by 1

```
RANK = 
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        'Max Avg',
        'Max Avg'[Attribute] = EARLIER ( 'Max Avg'[Attribute])
    ),
    'Max Avg'[Criteria Avg],
    ,
    DESC,
    DENSE
)
```

expected result is :

[image: result]

Can you suggest an easier way ?

[This is PBix file where you can work on to suggest a faster way](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1K-9s7BfEsIBByTo_NtO3E-NTpA38mFUW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is the best solution! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only by creating a couple of complicated measures. BTW, I'd always reshape data in PQ rather than DAX. Here is an alternative:

Create a criteria table.

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Attribute = 
VAR a = ADDCOLUMNS( 
            SUMMARIZE(YourTableName, YourTableName[Department ID]) ,    
            "@crit1", CALCULATE(AVERAGE(YourTableName[Criteria 1])),
            "@crit2", CALCULATE(AVERAGE(YourTableName[Criteria 2])),
            "@crit3", CALCULATE(AVERAGE(YourTableName[Criteria 3]))
        )
return 
SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Criteria[Criteria]),
 "Criteria 1", MAXX(a, [@crit1]),
 "Criteria 2", MAXX(a, [@crit2]),
 "Criteria 3", MAXX(a, [@crit3])
 )
```

Add to a table visual

[image]

Result

[image]

Comment: This is better for several Criteria columns, but if you have 40 or 100...

Comment: Agreed. It was just an alternative but really the data needs reshaping in PQ.

Comment: @David thank you for your time. Result needs the department ID as well ;)

Comment: It is basically the same measure repeated but retrieving department. I can add it if you like and you think you will use the solution.

Comment: @David I will try to add it by myself so I can practice more ;) thanks mate…

Comment: Let me know if you need me to add and I'll do so tomorrow